# Drawing a zigzag (Spring) in java

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt

I am currently making a program which animates the simple harmonic motion of a mass-spring when it is displaced. I have everything working apart from the fact that instead of drawing something like a spring, my program currently uses the graphics.drawline method to draw a straight line to represent the spring. I ideally want something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuuKq.png) however I am not very experienced with graphics and don't really know how to approach it, I tried to make an algorithm myself but it kept falling apart. Does anyone know of any existing algorithms which I could utilise here? If the stretching of the spring looked realistic then that would be great too (if possible).

Here is my current code:

```
    g.fillRect(width/10 - 2, height/2 - 10, 4, 20);
    g.fillRect(9*width/10 - 2, height/2 - 10, 4, 20);

    g.drawLine(width/10, height/2, (int) (width/2 - (sCoefficientH * s)), height/2);
    g.fillOval((int) (width/2 - (sCoefficientH * s)) -5, height/2 - 5, 10, 10);
```

As you can see there is a line connecting the wall (small rectangle) to the oval (which represents the mass on the spring). If I could add in a new method in this class which takes 2 co-ordinates and a relaxed size (where it wouldn't look compressed) and returns the graphics object (note that I'm not using Graphics2D) with the spring drawn in the correct place then I think it would look a lot nicer. [This](https://gyazo.com/aba34c7c9b71742ba1bd3457bd89b5b8) is what it looks like currently.

Comment: I'll have a go. Would you like it to be vertical or horizontal? Would you like to be able to specify the number of coils or the dimensions (width etc)?

Comment: @willywonka_dailyblah Thank you so much! My simulation can be either orientation. The input that the user will give is the natural length of the spring and the original extension so maybe the longer the natural length the larger the amount of coils. The 'sCoefficientH' in my code is to make it so no matter the length inputted the end of the spring will always travel through the same area so if there is a different amount of coils for longer lengths then that would be really cool. What sort of algorithm are you thinking about? A combination of drawlines?

Comment: I'll try doing a _general_ spring type where you only have to specify the endpoints of the spring, and it will rotate the spring accordingly. I'll make it possible for you to specify the width and number of coils. btw I don't understand your 'sCoefficientH' - do you mean a sort of Poisson factor?

Comment: @willywonka_dailyblah It's defined as: sCoefficientH = (4 * this.width) / (10 * natL);     I use it because the user can say they want a spring that is 100m long but I don't have a screen width large enough for that. The calculation of how the spring moves uses the natural length of the spring and so it will output the value in meters. The purpose of sCoefficientH is to convert the physical value (in meters)  into something (in pixels) that will fit on the screen. Thank you so much for your help by the way.

Comment: I'll just let you specify the screen coordinates and let you sort out the scale yourself; just trying not to insult your intelligence :)

Comment: willywonka_dailyblah That is exactly what I need. Thank you. I'm not very good at programming although I should probably put more effort into learning since I study Mathematics.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105291/discussion-between-willywonka-dailyblah-and-loua).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
void drawSpring(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double w, int N, Graphics g)
{
   // vector increment
   double inv = 0.25 / (double)N;
   double dx = (x2 - x1) * inv,
          dy = (y2 - y1) * inv;

   // perpendicular direction
   double inv2 = w / sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
   double px =  dy * inv2, 
          py = -dx * inv2;

   // loop
   double x = x1, y = y1;
   for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
   {
      g.drawLine(x                , y                , 
                 x +       dx + px, y +       dy + py);
      g.drawLine(x +       dx + px, y +       dy + py,
                 x + 3.0 * dx - px, y + 3.0 * dy - py);
      g.drawLine(x + 3.0 * dx - px, y + 3.0 * dy - py,
                 x + 4.0 * dx     , y + 4.0 * dy     );
      x += 4.0 * dx;
      y += 4.0 * dy;
   }
}
```

Maybe change `Graphics` to whatever the equivalent is in Java.

EDIT: what I got in VB.NET:
[image]

Comment: Thank you! If you wouldn't mind, what does N represent? and is w is width?

Comment: @Loua w is width of the spring yes. N is the number of coils. attached picture is N = 5, w = 50